# Use data from first spreadsheet in second spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

In Google Sheets, when you have a spreadsheet open, there's an option to add another sheet. The sheets in this document are then shown as tabs on the bottom.

Say I have the following data in Sheet 1:

```
   A  | B
------|---
 lorem|  1
 ipsum|  2
 dolor|  3
```

I would like to make Sheet 2 based on the data in Sheet 1.

For example, I'd like to include `=SUM(B1:B3)` in Sheet 2, referring to the data in Sheet 1.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply include the sheet name. So, assuming the first sheet is named 'Sheet1', you'd use the formula

```
=SUM(Sheet1!B1:B3)
```

Note that if the name has spaces, you'd have to use single quotes around the name. So, assuming the sheet is named Sheet 1, you'd use

```
=SUM('Sheet 1'!B1:B3)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!